# PHP search bar to filter HTML table breaks on NULL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple html table being populated by my mysql database, and a function that is creating a new query in php, that will then be loaded into the query which is used to populate the table as a means of filtering it down.  The issue becomes that when there is a value of `NULL` in my database instead of just being an empty value, it breaks the statement.

Below is the value to generate the SQL which will populate the table after filtering:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
      $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];

      $query = "SELECT * FROM PatientEventLog WHERE CONCAT(`patientEventLogID`, `patientEventID`, `patientID`, `eventCreatorID`, `eventEdited`, `antibiotic`, `waterBroke`, `vertex`, `cervixDilation`, `effacedPercent`, `station`, `membranes`, `analgesia`, `augment`, `notes`, `visible`) LIKE '%" . $valueToSearch ."%'";
      echo "value to search:   \n";
      echo $valueToSearch;
      echo "\n \n       above search resluts";
      echo $query;
      echo "below search results";
      $search_result = filterTable($query);

  } else {
    $query = "select * from PatientEventLog";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);

  }

  function filterTable($query) {
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "GMd-eUJ-L6m-RxF", "lndappDB");
    $filter_results = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    echo $filter_results;
    return $filter_results;

  }
?>
```

Why would this like statement not be picking up these `NULL` values?

Comment: Sidenote: this is vulnerable to SQL injection - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection

Comment: @DerekH I did understand that, I just wanted to get it working first.  Also this is an admin site, so it will require proper credentials to even access this page, which is why I am less worried about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)  operator:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM PatientEventLog 
  WHERE CONCAT(
  COALESCE(`patientEventLogID`,''), 
  COALESCE(`patientEventID`,''), 
  COALESCE(`patientID`,''), 
  COALESCE(`eventCreatorID`,''), 
  COALESCE(`eventEdited`,''), 
  COALESCE(`antibiotic`,''), 
  COALESCE(`waterBroke`,''), 
  COALESCE(`vertex`,''), 
  COALESCE(`cervixDilation`,''),
  COALESCE(`effacedPercent`,''), 
  COALESCE(`station`,''), 
  COALESCE(`membranes`,''), 
  COALESCE(`analgesia`,''), 
  COALESCE(`augment`,''), 
  COALESCE(`notes`,''), 
  COALESCE(`visible`,'')
) LIKE '%" . $valueToSearch ."%'";
```

But will be better to use `$valueToSearch` as parameter to avoid MySQL injection, here is an example: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496)